# Passing EntityManager to Transformers within nested forms in Symfony4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, nested

To start with...
I am fairly new to Symfony (using Symfony 4.0).
I am trying to build a "small" package for administering music sheets. My database is MySQL.
To start with, I got a "rudimentary" form displayed, so that I can enter the data about "Persons". Persons may in the end be composers, arrangers (some of them both at the same time).
My PersonType form works just fine when used on its own and data entered get persisted to the database alright. More than one of the form fields use Transformers.

However, when embedding a PersonType form within a ComposerType form, I get the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Form\DataTransformer\GeschlechtToCodeTransformer::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, null given, called in /home/rainermusik/musikdb/src/Form/Type/PersonenType.php on line 51

In my controller (ComposerController) I pass the EntityManager at form creation:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(KomponistenType::class, $komponist, array(
    'entityManager' => $em
));
```

The ComposerFormType is:

```php
class KomponistenType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $em = $options['entityManager'];

        $builder
            ->add('person', PersonenType::class, array(
                'label'  => false
            ))
            ->add('infodatei', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Informationsdatei zum Komponisten: '
            ))
            ->add('fertig', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Eingabe'
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => \App\Entity\Komponisten::class,
            'entityManager' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

The PersonenType form definition is the following:

```php
class PersonenType extends AbstractType
{
    private $transformer;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
  // public function __construct(GeschlechtToCodeTransformer $transformer)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $em = $options['entityManager'];

        $builder
            ->add('famname', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Familienname: '
            ))
            ->add('vorname', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Vorname: '
            ))
            ->add('titel', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Titel: '
            ))
            ->add('titel2', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Titel2: '
            ))
            ->add('titel3', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Titel3: '
            ))
            ->add('anrede2', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  =>'Brief-Anrede (z. B. Sehr geehrter Herr XY): '
            ))
            ->add('geschlecht', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Geschlecht (m/w): ',
                'invalid_message' => 'falsche Angabe zu Geschlecht der Person',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => 'm'
            ))
            ->add('formell', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Formell (j/n)?: ',
                'invalid_message' => 'falsche Angabe zu formell/informell',
                'required' => false, 'empty_data' => 'j'
            ))
            ->add('bemerkung', TextType::class, array(
                'label'  => 'Bemerkungen: ',
                'required' => false, 'empty_data' => ''
            ))
            ->add('fertig', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Eingabe'
            ))
        ;

        $this->transformer = new GeschlechtToCodeTransformer($em);
        $builder->get('geschlecht')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
        $this->transformer = new FormellInformellToCodeTransformer($em);
        $builder->get('formell')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => \App\Entity\Personen::class,
            'entityManager' => null
        ));
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the PersonType form functions just fine when used "on its own" to enter a new Person. When included in a ComposerType (KomponistenType), it does not recognise the $em specified.

I am really stuck after hours of "playing around".
Regards from icy Salzburg
H. Stoellinger

Comment: Start with [defining your form as a service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service).  And then perhaps dive into the service container chapter in the docs.  Be sure to read the correct version of the docs.  Services have undergone considerably changes over time.

Comment: Thanks, Cerad! Unless I don't yet understand enough -- It seems that defining the forms as a service happens automatically when using autowire/autoconfigure. But, I will certainly dive into the Services / Container chapter. I hope I won't drown in it...

Comment: Yep.  From what I can tell autwire should work for you.  You should inject the entity manager into the transformer then the transformer into the form.  I suspect you were trying to new the transformer somewhere.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment! In the end it turned out to be a "typo", such as an apostrophy (" or ') too many. I am one step further on now and - of course - I have hit on another issue...